# How to access Google+ photos from my website

Tags: web-services, google-plus

I would like to build a website that shows for every logged user the latest 10 photos uploaded to his Google+ account.

Sorry for what sounds like a basic question... but is that thing possible?

If yes, what is the best solution for this use case?

Thank you
Rami

Answer (score 1):

There is currently not a photos API for Google+. You can search public posts for a user and determine which contain images, but that's it for now.

However, you can authorize the user and then [access their photos using the GData API and Picassa web](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol). Find the album_instant_upload album and if you're authorized, you can access the recently uploaded albums.